# Using Google Maps v2 in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

i am trying to integrate Google Maps to my Android Application. I followed this tutorial: https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435.
I did everything as suggested. 
These are the errors in the error log:

```
E/Google Maps Android API(28238): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
E/Google Maps Android API(28238): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API(28238): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.kontrollen, API Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Certificate Fingerprint: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And this is my google account:
[image]

Do you have any ideas what i can do?

This is my AndroidManifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kontrollen"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<permission android:name="com.example.kontrollen.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.kontrollen.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.kontrollen.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is it definitely the right key? Remember your debug key (what you develop with) is different from your production key (what you sign with).

Comment: You should follow the official tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

Comment: I know it. I used the fingerprint of the debug.keystore file. What implies the orange exclamation mark in the screenshot?

Comment: Are you using a MapView or a MapFragment in your application?  There is a slight difference in how one should initialize each...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem by uninstalling the app and cleaning the project folder. I did not change anything. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer:

Try putting the meta-data within the application tag, preferably right before the closing tag like

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xyz" />
</application>
```

Comment: I used the debug.keystore from C:\Users\xxxx\.android\debug.keystore. I got the SHA1 fingerprint and entered it. So i do not know what i might do wrong. And I followed this instruction.

Comment: Does Google Maps Android API v2 show up as a service in the Overview tab? If not, go to the services tab and enable it.

Comment: It is in the overview tab. It says: Google Maps Android API v2  No known issues. I copied the fingerprint from Eclipse "Window->Preferences->Build", so it should be right.

Comment: Can you post your Manifest?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not make a change. :(

Answer (score 1):

follow the url to create your app google api key i have done this recently.. and it was successful.

https://code.google.com/apis/console/    ------------ For Google API
 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start  ------------ Crate Map

**read these page carefully every thing is given in this page** .. follow the same but make sure you have generated correct SHA1 fingerprint

and when you are going to crate the app make sure run it on real device because it need google play services to run add google pay services in your application

Comment: I can read the same fingerprint from Eclipse ("Preferences->Window->Build").

Comment: no you have to create your fingerprint from command prompt and use them in to google cnsole api

Comment: I did it as well. It is the same for sure. I used keytool of jre7.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps to trace error youself
**STEPS**
for your error type

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

1.check for internet or gsf reader permissions in manifest as shown above.
2.check for the package name you used in you manifest.
3.check in your api console the service that you started is `Google Maps Android API v2`.
4.Check the library google play services is imported or not.
5.if no solution is working try out new way following this link--         https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start.

6.Also keytool command to generate sha1--i used is-
  keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:/Users/username/.android/debug.keystore

Comment: 1-3) checked 4) The android-support-v4.jar and google-play-services.jar are in "Android Private Libraries" and the google-play-services_lib.jar is in "Android Dependencies". Might this cause the error? I also checked 5 and 6.

Comment: all lib files should be in android dependencies folder...and to do that right click the lib file that is not availabe in android dependencies folder and click on add to build path.

Answer (score 1):

I had actually made a maps activity from the studio and used the link it generated to set up the maps API. Where I went wrong was, I placed it inside a package and the package name that was registered for the app was with that folder name. For Ex.
If app package name is

```
com.awesome.shit
```

the package that was saved in API was

```
com.awesome.shit.maps
```

changed it and it started working.